# How to run django orm query without using field name?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

So i have one json data that contain field name of model as json key with value. i want to run orm query and define field name on run time.

Ex:

```
json_data = {"postgres_id":"10"}

query = AcronymSecurityControlMaster.objects.get(postgres_id=10) 

json_data = {"age":"10"}

query = AcronymSecurityControlMaster.objects.get(age=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary unpacking to pass a dictionary as the named parameters of a function call:

```
json_data = {"age": 10}
#                           dictionary unpacking ↓↓
query = AcronymSecurityControlMaster.objects.get(**json_data)
```

You however should validate that the `json_data` does not contain any security vulnerabilities. For example a user could try to "guess" sensitive data with:

```
{ userfield__name='aabbcc' }
```

where you perhaps do not want to share the name of the user.